# ServiceStack - OnEndRequest capturing Response body

Tags: servicestack

I have a RequestLog feature completely decoupled from the application logic.

I capture the request/response in a pre request filter. To acomplish this, I instantiate a request scope object that keeps the request context. And before everything gets disposed (at AppHost's OnEndRequest handler), I write to the db. One line per http req.

I'm able to access the response code, the path, the method, request body, request headers, etc.

However the response stream is not available as it was already disposed. What's the logic behind this? Is it something like, IIS writes the stream content to the wire, and releases the resource imediately? Is there any way I can capture the Response body at the OnEndRequest handler?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, ServiceStack doesn't buffer the Response stream it gets written directly to the ASP.NET response.

You can add a Global Response Filter or [Custom ServiceRunner](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Customize-HTTP-Responses#wiki-using-a-custom-servicerunner) to capture the Services response if the [request reaches that far](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations), but the request can be short-circuited at anytime throughout the request pipeline by closing the response.

Comment: Yes I know that. In fact that is the reason I grab everything at a pre-request filter, and dump them to the database at "OnEndRequest". I wanted the illusion of a post request filter. The idea is to have a request logger that contains all the requests that enter the sshttphandlerfactory. This behavior is not achieved with the standard RequestLogsFeature as is, because of the "short circuting". Is there any particular reason this scenario wasn't contemplated?

Comment: Contemplated?? Short-circuiting is a feature and responses are always written directly to the response stream as expected. Look at the first entry in the Request Pipeline to get notified of every request, i.e. Register a RawHttpHandler, you want to return null so you don't hijack the request.

Comment: I just trying to get your view on the importance of such a Logger/Feature. Maybe you have reasons to think it is not relevant since it is not strongly contemplated in ServiceStack (the RequestLogFeature is a servicerunner thing). But i guess the answer is use HttpRawHandler. I'm assuming I still wont get access to the raw output body, which was what I intended. This way, it would be decoupled from any other feature that writes to the response and closes the request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with capturing the response in ServiceRequestLogger. Read this post - it is solved in 4.0.39+ (currently pre-release)

[ServiceStack response filter "short circuiting" causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883800/servicestack-response-filter-short-circuiting-causing-problems)