# ServiceStack response filter "short circuiting" causing problems

Tags: servicestack

We have embraced SS as our REST server platform and love it - one of the recurring issues I face deals with logging requests that have been "short circuited" for one legitimate reason or another (errors, missing mandatory headers, etc).

I am finding that I have to add extra logging code to many different code exit (ie short circuited) points because I still want to capture the request in the logs. Am I doing something wrong here? is there a way to specify a "mandatory response filter" that occurs even after short circuiting. I could see multiple uses for this beyond just logging...

Thanks in advance,

Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `AppHost.OnEndRequest()` which gets called at the end of each request.

Comment: That would be funny if it wasn't so painful.

Comment: it sounds like OnEndRequest is the place I'm looking for... but its missing the SS request and response context. Any plans to add this in the future?

Comment: @jglassco I've just changed `OnEndRequest()` to callback with `IRequest` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/e65dce4bfd405006a6c2680e77ed08fd343b6eec). This change is available from v4.0.39 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).